# CURL to store and retrieve cookies

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to write a script for analytics. I've good experience in PHP, but not very good at CURL. The basic purpose of the below script is to,

1. Login to a XYZ.COM using PHP Script and save cookies to a local file.
2. Going forward, I want to use this local cookies file and then want to extract details from pages(of XYZ.COM) which get access only after login process. Everything is through Script. So, authentication is must to access these pages.

I can get authenticated to website with my details(through the script sucessfully), but I can't store cookies, and next time when I call the page, it asks for authentication again. I'm not able to understand where script went wrong/my way of approach is wrong.

This is the script that I created:

```
<?php

function postData($url, $params)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0");
    $cookie_file = "cookie1.txt";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function getData($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$params = array(
"login" => "USERNAME",
"pass" => "PASSWORD",
"remember" => 0,

);
$url = "http://www.WEBSITE_WITH_POST_FORUM_TARGET.com/services/login";
echo postData($url, $params);
echo getData("http://www.SAME_WEBSITE.com"); // HERE WHEN I LOAD THE WEBSITE, IT AGAIN ASKS FOR AUTHENTICATION.
?>
```

Kindly let me know, if its difficult to understand.

Comment: You are not the first one who asks this. I suggest you to use the search instead creating a new question. Also your question can greatly benefit from a more tidies up code-formatting, take a little care when you ask a question, this code for example does not demonstrate your issue, it is just a copy and paste from your larger script, but it is not the example that would demonstrate your issue. We nowadays more and more require that you show demonstration code, not just your code.

Comment: Exact duplicate of the first entry in the related column on the right.

Comment: @undone: You just have shown that you don't understand which ones the proper options are. I don't like to repeat myself, but just to underline and make it crystal clear in a response to your comment, the exact duplicate (the first entry in the related column on the right) contains the correct options. When in doubt, consult the Curl manual.

Comment: @hakre I've seen the duplicate threat posted. But, I see only cookies file being created. Nothing is stored in that file. Another task after storing cookies into a specific file is to use that cookies file to get authenticated next time automatically.

Comment: There is no reason to argue with me about that, as written, technical details of this should be discussed in the duplicate material, not here. If you implemented duplicate material, please highlight in your question what you tried as well, reference each of those related questions from where you applied those other tries, outline what exactly didn't work for you so it's more clear why this requires a new question on this Q&A site. BTW do you know actually what the options are for Curl to deal with cookies? Why do you expect your code to work at all for cookies? Please elaborate.